# Firebase createUser.addOnCompleteListener is not entering in onCreate method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following piece of code:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha)
    .addOnCompleteListener(CadastroActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("SuccessInCreateUser", task.getException().toString());
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("ErrorInCreateUser", task.getException().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

When I execute the app, the user IS created as expected but it never go through the onComplete method, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Code is okay.  Does the device or emulator you are testing on have the current version of Google Play Services?  Can you post the build.gradle file for your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think there is no need to put task.isSuccesful() as it's already onComplete() callback. Would ask you to try following snippet:*

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha)
            .addOnCompleteListener(CadastroActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("SuccessInCreateUser", "No exception");
                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());

                    //Catch specific exception here like this. Below is the example of password less than 6 char - weak password exception catch
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Weak Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }




        });
```

Do let me know if it changes anything for you.